# I want to plant 5 species of plants in my garden, which can purify the air around the garden and also keep away mosquitoes . Suggest some to me

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations, container-gardening, urban-gardening, ornamental-plant

I have a garden in my house where I had some plants earlier. They were mostly flowering plants. Now I am looking for some plants which can purify the air around the house, keep away mosquitoes, and also look good. Please suggest some.
I plan to keep them outdoors and my garden receives a very good amount of light, I am flexible with the container sizes as I have ample space in the garden. 
PS: I live in India.

Comment: Good question; if could include the region, container size(s), if intend to have them in containers, amount of light, if will be placed exclusively indoors or outdoors, or both, and amount of space available, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Knowing what part of the world you are in is critical in terms of what plants you can grow, so can you add your location please.

Comment: Note: no plant could purify air outdoor (but if you build a forest): plants are weak at purifying air, and there is too much circulation of air outside. Watering system (or fountains) helps much more (but then... mosquitoes)

Comment: I meant something like Aerica palms and other plants are known to purify the air. So I was asking something like that.

Comment: KUSHAGRABANSAL I'm afraid that @GiacomoCatenazzi is right. Even Areca palms will only purify air if they're in an enclosed space, outside just has too much air movement, so new contaminants can always blow in faster than the plant will clear them. I don't have 5 plants that come to mind for mosquitoes, but  one that you might try is Citronella Geraniums.